# What is the proper way for installation phonegap application also the correct environment setting

Tags: cordova, ant, npm

[image]

i got this error also i install the ant file and fixed the path environment  also but still its showing error . please help

Comment: Do you have apache ant installed and added to your path?

Comment: Please avoid using CAPITAL letters for the whole sentence. It looks horrible...

Answer (score 0):

In environment variable

Create NEW variable

ANT_HOME C:\Path\to\ant-without-bin

Edit PATH. 
append C:\Path\to\ant-1.x.x\bin